# Libraries to build karaoke software on raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, cloud-service, raspberry-pi, cloud

I am trying to understand karaoke software that play at karaoke bar and I would like to build know. I have been researching for this and they build that on raspberry Pi using Python but I'm not sure how to start. Song are control via website that host on cloud and I believe all files are storing on cloud as well.
[image]

Comment: Did you search? There seem to be Python modules out there. Do you have access to the actual karaoke files?

Comment: @Mawg Yes, I did search and found 2 example code which written in python. this program is controlling by website on mobile but I'm not sure how backend are connecting together. I think maybe socket and websocket.

Comment: [The first hit](https://github.com/hsocasnavarro/Karapython) on a Google search says "Python module to read karaoke .kar files". Do you have  .kar files?

Comment: Did you look on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=karaoke) and [GitHub](https://github.com/hsocasnavarro/Karapython/search?q=karaoke&unscoped_q=karaoke)?

Comment: @Mawg I have mp4 file and cdg files. I'm curious how you will control this software via web browser.

Comment: You are new around here (welcome) - you really ought to have said that in your question (edit it now). The more information you give us, the more likely that we can help you. Please read [ask]. I think the first question is how you synchronize the MP3 and [cdg](https://file.org/extension/cdg) files.

Comment: @Mawg I'm think storing files on AWS s3 or firebase cloud storage then have websocket on python start a server. After starting a server I will creating a browser connect to my server. My question is how can I control my player that playing on a screen through mobile website ?